# Setting Trac with Apache and mod_fcgi results in either 404 or 403

Tags: apache-2.2, trac, arch-linux, mod-fcgid

I am trying to create a trac installation on my private server in order to use it for project management.
I followed the instructions for installation and connecting to the apache server that can be found at the [official trac installation guide](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall) but when I try to access trac I get error 404. When I disable ScriptAlias, I get 403 Access Denied. Here are the details:

My setup is like that:
ArchLinux i686 running in headless mode (I connect to it via ssh) and connected wirelessly to my home network's router. 
I chose to connect trac and apache with FastCGI

A trac user to contain everything trac related.

```
$ sudo ls /home/trac
cgi-bin  env  htdocs
```

env is where the projects are located
cgi-bin and htdocs were generated with the `trac-admin $TARGET $DESTINATION deploy` command.

A httpd user to contain the DocumentRoot for the apache server:

```
$ sudo ls /home/httpd
ftp  http
```

I gave ownership to everythin in /home/trac, recursively, to httpd and the http group (insecure, I know, but I wanted to test it out first in the simplest way possible):

```
sudo chown -R http.httpd /home/trac
```

I made the following modifications to httpd.conf:

Added:

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
```

Changed:

```
User httpd
Group http
```

Changed DocumentRoot to this everywhere:

```
DocumentRoot "/home/httpd/http"
```

And finally I enabled virtual hosts:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Here is the httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin myemail@email.com
DocumentRoot "/home/trac/"
ServerName SERVER_IP
ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/trac.error.log"
CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/trac.access.log" combined

<Location />
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.0.0/16 127.0.0.1
</Location>
<Location /env>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    AuthName "Trac Projects"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /home/trac/.htpasswd
    Satisfy Any
    Require valid-user
</Location>
ScriptAlias /env /home/trac/cgi-bin/trac.fcgi
```

Note that I have made the trac.fcgi owned by http as well as explicitly set the permissions ot make it executable.

When ScriptAlias is commented, I get 403 Access Denied for the root, SERVER_IP, as well as SERVER_IP/env or any other directory in the path. When the line is not commented, I get 403 Access Denied for the root and 404 Object Not Found for everything else.

The sources that I used to arrive at this point are first the [tracinstall guide](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall) and then the outdated [arch linux install guide](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnArchLinux) when the first one did not work (produced the same results that I am describing, only I was able to arrive at the dummy page in the DocumentRoot, and even with the script alias enabled the SERVER_IP/env was Access Denied 403).
Here is the httpd.conf as it is way too big to post here:
[httpd.conf](https://github.com/kzvezdarov/etc/blob/master/apache/httpd.conf)

I think that this is a permission problem but my because of my limited experience with apache I cannot seem to reach a solution.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Since I am controlling the whole thing through ssh, logged in as a different user, I had to give httpd ownership of its http and ftp directories after I created them. I am not sure if this matters though.

Answer (score 1):

Note, there is a dedicated [FastCGI setup wiki page](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFastCgi) linked in the generic installation guide. Note too, that wsgi is the recommended setup for Trac these days.

But if you want it for private use only, I doubt seriously, that this is all worth the hassle. It might be educational, right, but I bet that the standalone setup with *tracd* will bring you up and running Trac itself in a few minutes.

Related to access/authentication, you should have at least one user in your */home/trac/.htpasswd*, and the same user (prefer lower-case, no fancy stuff like spaces, etc.) must be registered in Trac and given appropriate permission. For the start you should add the first user as Trac admin using *trac-admin* like

```
$> trac-admin /home/trac permission add <username> TRAC_ADMIN
```

Replace username with your choice and as usual you should have at least another user with regular permission (after login permissions of the *authenticated* group apply).